# Altering $_POST in PHPUnit/Selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, simpletest

I need to add a value to $_POST, specifically 'port' so I can tell my test submission to go through fakemail.

[The fakemail documentation](http://www.lastcraft.com/fakemail.php) shows how to insert a value to $_POST with SimpleTest:

```
$this->clickSubmit('Send', array('port' => 10025));
```

In PHPUnit, this doesn't work:

```
$this->click("//input[@value='Send']", array('port' => 10025));
```

I'm very unfamiliar with all the concepts behind testing, so this may be simpler than I'm making it. How would you get the job done using PHPUnit/Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this in phpunit, but in Selenium IDE you are able to change hidden fields using javascript.

Test page:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

<br/><br/>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="hhh" name="hhh" value="orig"/>
    <input type="text" name="ttt"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sss"/>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Script (generated from firefox IDE, so haven't tested it):

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://localhost/test.php");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->type("ttt", "bbb");
    $this->runScript("javascript{ this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('hhh').value = 'new2'; }");
    $this->click("sss");
  }
}
?>
```

So just add the `port` variable as a hidden field and set the value with javascript.